# ¿Cómo mostrar en el menú activo un listado de opciones/menú?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy imitando el diseño de esta plantilla **CMS** como se puede observar en el diseño de la imagen se observa que en el menú activo **Dashboard** muestra un listado de opciones del panel de control **CMS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He logrado imitar la mayor parte de la plantilla en mi menú vertical muestro el primer menú activo y he creado un margen entre el cuerpo de los datos ***(formularios etc)*** y donde se mostrará el listado del menú.

> Me gustaría añadirle también un triángulo o flecha como identificador al menú que se encuentre activo realmente no se como se llama lo muestro en una imagen que diseñe desde el programa Fireworks 8, busque ejemplos pero no he encontrado ninguno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi plantilla CMS**

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav-menu-side li').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.nav-menu-side ul li').removeClass("active");
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans', 'cursive', 'Raleway', Roboto, Lato, Utsaah;
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}
.menu-top {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  height: 53px;
  width: 100%;
}
.notification{
  float: left;
  margin: .3em 0 0 1em;
}
.profile_details {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 4.8em 0 1em;
}
.sticky {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}
.menu-side {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #37474F; /* #0F6188;*/
  width: 60px;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
}
#page-wrapper {
  padding: 6em 2em;
  margin-left: 200px;
  min-height: 2580px !important;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav-menu-side {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.nav-menu-side ul {
  margin: 2px 0 20px 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-menu-side ul:before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.nav-menu-side ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
.nav-menu-side ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  display: block;
}
.nav-menu-side ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #415058;
}
.nav-menu-side ul li a i {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.nav-menu-side ul li a span {
  position: absolute;
  background: #8BC34A;
  padding: 11.7px;
  left: 52px;
  top: 1px;
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-menu-side>ul li+li {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.nav-menu-side .active {
  background-color: #415058;
}
.icon-insight {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 29px;
  background-image: url(insight.svg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="menu-top">
  <div class="user-panel">
<div class="notification"></div>
<div class="profile"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="menu-left" class="sticky menu-side">
  <!-- Contenido del menú admin-->
  <div class="nav-menu-side">
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page-wrapper">
  <h1>Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms</h1>
</div>
```

**Ahora mi problema es** cómo muestro en los menú activos o el menú que se encuentre activo un listado de menú de opciones como muestra la primera imagen que estoy imitando.

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien, estás pidiendo como crear el triangulo o flecha para menus activos. Y eso, puede hacerse mediante CSS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav-menu-side li').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.nav-menu-side ul li').removeClass("active");
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans', 'cursive', 'Raleway', Roboto, Lato, Utsaah;
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}
.menu-top {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  height: 53px;
  width: 100%;
}
.notification{
  float: left;
  margin: .3em 0 0 1em;
}
.profile_details {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 4.8em 0 1em;
}
.sticky {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}
.menu-side {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #37474F; /* #0F6188;*/
  width: 60px;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
}
#page-wrapper {
  padding: 6em 2em;
  margin-left: 200px;
  min-height: 2580px !important;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav-menu-side {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.nav-menu-side ul {
  margin: 2px 0 20px 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-menu-side ul:before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.nav-menu-side ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
.nav-menu-side ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  display: block;
}
.nav-menu-side ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #415058;
}
.nav-menu-side ul li a i {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.nav-menu-side ul li a span {
  position: absolute;
  background: #8BC34A;
  padding: 11.7px;
  left: 52px;
  top: 1px;
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-menu-side>ul li+li {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.nav-menu-side .active {
  background-color: #415058;
}
.icon-insight {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 29px;
  background-image: url(insight.svg);
}

.active:before{
   /* triangulito */
    border-color: transparent whitesmoke transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 8px;
    content: "";
    display: block;   
    right: -45px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    width: 0px;  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-left" class="sticky menu-side">
  <!-- Contenido del menú admin-->
  <div class="nav-menu-side">
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="icon-insight"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page-wrapper">
  <h1>Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms Basic Forms</h1>
</div>
```

He cogido tu código y le he añadido los estilos a la clase `active`

Para profundizar más en el tema te dejo [este enlace](https://cybmeta.com/formas-basicas-con-css-triangulos-circulos-trapecios-rectangulos-cuadrados) y [este](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) otro :)

Saludos!